# Which camera parameters are we changing with mouse scroll wheel?

Tags: camera

In Blender, from the object data tab for the camera we can change:

focal length/fov & sensor width/height

but when we scroll the mouse wheel in the camera view, we zoom in/out on that camera view.  When we do this, I don't see the focal length/fov parameter get updated in the camera's object data tab.  So which camera parameter
are we updating when we scroll the middle mouse button in the camera view?  Thanks.

Comment: Those parameters are valid only for the rendered picture, and the mouse scroll's zoom doesn't affect it.